What makes the "CRM Analytics Dashboard" LWC component available in an org so that a managed package referencing that component will install?
This is a re-ask of this question How to enabled CRM Analytics Dashboard Component in App Builder? that has no definitive answer.
I have built an embedded CRM Analytics app (one that does not require a full CRM Analytics license) using the steps here CRM Analytics (AKA Wave, Einstein) packaging questions. This installs and works in a Developer Edition org. And when you go to the Lightning App Builder (flexi-page editor) in a Developer Edition org you see that the CRM components are available:

But in production orgs the install fails with this error:

Your org doesn't have access to component wave:waveDashboardLwc.

and the CRM Analytics components are not available in the Lightning App Builder.
We are an OEM so provision licenses for our customers.
I can see no obvious differences in the permissions between the two orgs. What do I need to do so my managed package will install in a production org?
